# Is there a reason NOT to use Fastify (or Express) alone?

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs, fastify

In starting a new Node project, I'm considering using Fastify by itself.  Is this generally a bad decision?  I've considered using Nest.js (which can incorporate either Fastify or Express) but is this needed?

Is using Fastify or Express by themselves considered bad practice? Would an overlying framework like Nest.js provide considerably more than either of these alone?

Answer (score 1):

This question will be closed soon because it is not a programming question, and the answer is that it depends.

> I've considered using Nest.js (which can incorporate either Fastify or Express) but is this needed?

No, to use Fastify you don't need Nest.js.

> Is this generally a bad decision?

Do you know Nest.js?
If the answer is yes: go for it if you like it.
If the answer is no, you will need to learn Nest first, and then you need to learn Fastify if you want to use its features.

> Is using Fastify or Express by themselves considered bad practice?

No, I have tons apps in prod in pure Fastify way.
The covid APP backend of many nations was in pure Fastify: https://github.com/covidgreen/covid-green-backend-api

Of course, you must know that:

- More layers and frameworks
- = more things to know
- = more things that can go wrong
- = less control of what you can do

> Would an overlying framework like Nest.js provide considerably more than either of these alone?

First, I don't like Nest.js because:

- [it pins the fastify dependency](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/package.json#L134) so you can get fixes until nest will release a new version
- nobody is using fastify+nestjs in a good way because there are tons of [unanswered questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fastify+nestjs)
- if you need help, you can't ask to the fastify team. They tell you to ask to the nest team: https://github.com/fastify/help/issues/883

The only pro I see on using Nest.js is that it forces you and your team to write the same code structure and you can't go off those rails.

Meanwhile using pure fastify you can do what you want and your codebase could become a mess (I wrote a book about it, check my profile).

Comment: I've seen your book and I know you explain why you chose to use CJS instead of ESM throughout.  But even the Fastify website itself defaults to using ESM in its examples on the homepage.  There is no way I'm going to convince my group of devs to use CJS today.

Comment: Happy coding https://twitter.com/MicheleRivaCode/status/1638816473824088066?t=nc6VLTbDPKdNFqUqW9lGjg&s=19